# how to write the junit testcases for the switch case() statement?

Tags: java

I'm using the JUnit to write the `switch()` case statement.  I'm new to the JUnit environment. I really get stuck how to use JUnit write the `switch()` case

I really want to know how to do

thanks in advance.

Comparison: The Comparison type represents a comparison between two expressions. The Comparison type should contain the following enum type to represent the possible comparisons for the language (you are free to add additional operators if you wish):

```
public enum Operator { LT, LTE, GT, GTE, EQ, NEQ; }
```

The operators represent the `< <=, >, >=, ==,` and `!=` operations.
The Comparison type instance should be created with three arguments: an operation that is from the above Operator enum type, and two expressions that represent the left operand expression and the right operand expression. The type should allow any language structure that has an `int/Integer` value to be a possible expression. The Comparison type should have the following methods:

value: takes a state as input and returns the `boolean/Boolean` value that is the result of applying the operation to the values of each of the operand expressions. The state should be used to get the values of the expressions.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * create a class called ArithmeticOperation with generic type and implements toString interface
 * @author a13875810600
 *
 * @param <I>
 */
public class ArithmeticOperation <I> implements ToString{

    /**
     * create a enum Operator class with special Operators
     * @author a13875810600
     *
     */
     public enum Operator {
     Add, Sub, Mult, Div, Rem;
}
    // create field called leftoperand
    private Number leftoperand;
    // create field called operation
    private  Operator operation;
    // create field called rightoperand
    private Number rightoperand; 

    /**
     * creation of the  constructor of the ArithmeticOperation
     * @param leftoperand
     * @param operation
     * @param rightoperand
     */
    public ArithmeticOperation(Number leftoperand, Operator operation,Number rightoperand){
          this.leftoperand = leftoperand;
          this.operation =  operation;
          this.rightoperand = rightoperand;         
     }



   /**
    *  Demonstrate all cases of the enmu type by applying operation Operator to the leftoperand and 
    *  rightoperand and get values of the, Because only five types of emu if errors will occur it is because the Human only 
          recognize five types of operators 
    * @param s
    * @return 
    */
    public Integer value(State s){

         Integer result = 0;
         switch (this.operation) {
              case Add:
                   result = leftoperand.value(s) + rightoperand.value(s);
              case Sub:
                   result = leftoperand.value(s) - rightoperand.value(s);
              case Mult:
                   result = leftoperand.value(s) * rightoperand.value(s);
              case Div:
                   result = leftoperand.value(s) / rightoperand.value(s);
              case Rem:
                   result = leftoperand.value(s) % rightoperand.value(s);                   
         }
         return result;
     }
     }
```

Comment: do you understand why your code is bad? You have no break statements in your switch block, but you really need them, otherwise, every case you get will be: result = leftoperand.value(s) % rightoperand.value(s); 
it's the waterfall principle. For unit tests, what problem do you have with it?

Comment: Your code does not compile, you won't be able to test it...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments you need to add break statements to cases.

To test a switch case you need to write a separate test case for each operator.